# Place an array as an element to another array in C

Tags: arrays, c

I'm new to C and I'm having a hard time grasping the concept of making arrays.

I created the **first** 2d array to get the inputs by initializing the maximum possible entries I can have.

```
int max;
scanf("%d", &max);
int(*first)[n] = malloc(sizeof(int[n][n]));
```

After encoding the inputs, I have different unused space for every first[i] since each has different length. I received a memory limit exceeded so I would like to remove unused spaces. So, I created the **second** array and was planning to copy only the used spaces in the **first** array but I can't initialized the **second** array.

```
int second[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
     int len = length of first[i];
     int length[len];
     second[i] = length;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are specialized data structures optimized for these cases, like [sparse matrix](http://www.btechsmartclass.com/data_structures/sparse-matrix.html), but they may be a bit difficult to implement depending on your level of knowledge.

An easy solution (at the cost of fragmenting the memory) is to use the first element of each row as a sentinel indicating the number of columns that the row is going to have, I omit the error checks for brevity:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    size_t rows = (size_t)(rand() % 10 + 10);
    int **array = malloc(sizeof *array * rows);

    for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        int cols = rand() % 10 + 1;

        array[row] = malloc(sizeof **array * (size_t)(cols + 1));
        array[row][0] = cols;
        for (int col = 1; col < cols + 1; col++)
        {
            array[row][col] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
    for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        int cols = array[row][0];

        printf("%d cols: ", cols);
        for (int col = 1; col < cols + 1; col++)
        {
            printf("%d ", array[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        free(array[row]);
    }
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
9 cols: 7 7 4 7 4 7 5 6 9 
2 cols: 6 6 
3 cols: 4 6 7 
2 cols: 4 6 
6 cols: 4 0 9 3 6 0 
7 cols: 0 7 2 9 4 1 3 
2 cols: 6 0 
9 cols: 2 0 9 0 8 2 4 4 1 
9 cols: 0 7 5 7 8 4 2 4 6 
9 cols: 4 3 3 3 8 4 8 1 2 
2 cols: 0 4 
2 cols: 1 5 
2 cols: 5 1 
7 cols: 6 1 8 4 6 5 4 
3 cols: 7 0 9 
9 cols: 6 2 3 2 2 7 0 6 0
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a 2D array and don't know the size of each element, make an array of pointers. Then allocate exactly as much memory you need for each individual element.

A simple example would be storing each line of a file. Each line is an array of characters, but you don't know how long a line can be. It would be a huge waste to allocate a 2D array large enough to hold the biggest possible line. Instead, allocate a `char **`. This will be a list of `char *` strings.

```
const int max_lines = 1024;
char **lines = malloc(sizeof(char*) * max_lines);
```

This is 1024 pointers. Each pointer is only 4 or 8 bytes. So only about 8k of memory. There are ways to also avoid needing to allocate a fixed size here, but that's another answer.

Then read each line and only store as much as you need for each line.

```
int i = 0;
char line[BUFSIZ];
while( fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) ) {
  lines[i] = strdup(line);
  i++;
}
```

`line` is allocated using [`BUFSIZ`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output#Constants) to be large enough to fit most any line. And we reuse that to read lines of the file. But instead of storing all that extra memory, we use [`strdup`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) to copy the line to the minimum memory and store a pointer to that in `lines`.